# Django SelectDateWidget

Tags: django, date

```
date_range = 100    
this_year = date.today().year
birth_date= forms.DateField(label='What is your birth date?', widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(this_year - date_range, this_year+1)))
```

I would like to only select dates 100 years from today. But I currently can get values like Dec 31 2021 where sometimes the months and days don't match the correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django expects a list or tuple for `years` parameter in [SelectDateWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.SelectDateWidget).
Try with:

```
this_year = date.today().year
year_range = [x for x in range(this_year - 100, this_year + 1)]
birth_date = forms.DateField(
    label="What is your birth date?",
    widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=year_range),
)
```

Add a form field validator if you would like to check for a selected date within a specific range. Here's an example with a naive 100 years back calculation:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class YourForm():
    ...

    def clean_birth_date(self):
        birth_date = self.cleaned_data['birth_date']

        today = datetime.today()
        first_date = today - timedelta(days=100 * 365)

        if not (first_date < birth_date < today):
            raise ValidationError("Please select a date within the last 100 years")

        return data
```

Comment: Stills gets values for the days/month exceeding today

Comment: With years, you only filter the years. Not days or months. I think it would be best to add a form field validator to check the selected date according to your constraints.

Comment: Added a form field validation example.